# Payeezy api integration - check events

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, payeezy

I am trying to check my payeezy events online using follwoing url and api

https://developer.payeezy.com/payeezy-api/apis/get/events

I have set apikey and token and generated HMAC key for each time I generate request.

But getting following error response

```
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
206
Content-Type:
application/json
Date:
Fri, 27 May 2016 03:56:13 GMT
Server:
Apigee Router
{
  "fault": {
    "faultstring": "Execution of Hmac-authentication failed with error: Exception thrown from JavaScript : HMACERROR (hmac_helper#196)",
    "detail": {
      "errorcode": "steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailed"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest why this happening with me :(